# Can I have an Angular directive replaced with two elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a `<password>` directive which will contain an `<input>` followed by a `<span>` (an icon allowing the user to show/hide the password). Is it possible to have Angular replace the directive element in the HTML with these two elements and apply all attributes that exist on the directive element to the `<input>` element?

So:

```
<password ng-model="myVar" ng-change="myTrigger" ng-whatever="myWhatever"></password>
```

would become:

```
<span>
    <input type="password" ng-model="myVar" ng-change="myTrigger" ng-whatever="myWhatever"/>
    <span ng-click="togglePasswordVisibility()">show/hide</span>
</span>
```

and if the user adds any other attributes to `<password>` to have them applied on the `<input>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do it manually on element compile:

```
.directive('password', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span>' +
            '<input type="password" />' +
            '<span ng-click="togglePasswordVisibility()">show/hide</span>' +
          '</span>';
        compile: function($element, $attr) {
            return function($scope, $element, $attr) {
                var input = $element.find('input[type=password]'),
                    attributes = $element.prop("attributes");
                angular.forEach(attributes, function() {
                    input.attr(this.name, this.value);
                });
                $compile($input)($scope);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Haven't tested it, but I think this is the way to go (probably not the best one)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to test it and update it if anything's broken, but it looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use replace in directive, although I'd rename the directive or just add a prefix before it gets a problem

```
.directive('password', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<span>' +
          '<input type="password" ng-model="myVar" ng-change="myTrigger" ng-whatever="myWhatever"/>' +
          '<span ng-click="togglePasswordVisibility()">show/hide</span>' +
        '</span>'
    };
  });
```

Comment: This is far from what I am asking. This is the simplest directive possible. It will not pick up new attributes and it will call `togglePasswordVisibility()` from the scope in which it is used. This is nearly useless.

Comment: @Shomz: This proposed answer is ridiculous. You can play smart-ass all you want, but I don't see how the question could have been phrased clearer. Read the question again (the sentence ending with a question mark) and see the accepted answer.

Comment: @stackular Ah, sorry, now I see what you wanted to achieve. You were right.